# Error: Index Path on a UIButton (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, nsindexpath

I'm able to successfully append a phone number into the phoneNumbers array but when I try yo use indexPath, I get an error saying: "unrecognized selector sent to instance." Does this mean I can't use indexPath with the callButton function? If so, what alternative can I do?

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.callButton.addTarget(self, action: "callButton", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell

}

func callButton(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(phoneNumbers[indexPath.row])")!)

}
```

Comment: You have created your `@IBAction` using Interface Builder isn't? For what do you need the `indexPath` (`UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, etc)?

Comment: Yes, in Interface Builder. I need the indexPath because I am retrieving an array of phone numbers from Parse and want to assign each number to a unique call button in it's own table cell.

Comment: See my update answer, but I don't understand why you not define your cells data in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: My cells are defined in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The other cell properties (the imagview view and labels inside are defined there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes because after you have set you `@IBAction` using Interface Builder and its was registered as its target, you have changed its signature and added arguments and this make the `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Once you have define your `IBOutlet` for your `UIButoon` in your custom cell class, you can access and set anything you want for the class in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, like in the following way:

> **CustomTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

   var phoneNumber: Int!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

   @IBAction func callButton(sender: AnyObject) {
      println("Calling to \(self.phoneNumber)")
   }
}
```

And then in your `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` you can set what do you want for your `UIButton` like in the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Set the phone number according the indexPath.row of the cell to call later
    cell.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

When you set the `phoneNumber` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you're setting for each cell a different `phoneNumber`, it's the point of doing this inside the  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: These are custom cells so I have a custom class and I can't define an outlet outside of it?

Comment: No, you can't define an outlet outside the class for your cell.

Comment: Hm, well I'm not trying to change the title. I'm trying to have it so when a user clicks on the call button, the correct phone number is called. So I need to add the number to an array (I've done) and then call it using  UIApplication.sharedApplication(). Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my question with the code I'm using now but I'm still getting unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

Comment: @theActuary See updated answer, I thought the above solves your question.